# Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017: Error Message in VS2017 PRO

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed `Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017`. I am now finally able to create my database classes within VS2017 without switching back to VS2015.
After the installation I am getting the following error message upon opening an old project and also when creating a new Oracle database connection (in a new project) in Visual Studio 2017:

> oracle data provider for .net has been installed without a
>   machine-wide configuration
>   (...) Also found anoher version in the GAC that might be incompatible, please uninstall it and restart VS2017

(Poorly translated the german message to english, but you get the point)

Problem is: The version in my GAC is the newer version needed for VS2017. I definitly do not want to uninstall that, but the non machine wide data provider from earlier. I can't find anything about how to do that. Do you guys have any ideas?

Please forgive me if my attempt itself is not smart at all => I haven't installed Oracle Tools for VS before and ran into loads of problems doing so earlier.

Just for the record: I have been trying to google for a solution, but I did not manage to find one. If you got the key-Keywords let me know-

---

I installed [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html) Version from 6th july 2017

> Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (12.2.0.1.0)
>   This download includes:
>
> - Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 12.2.0.1.0 Oracle Data
> - Provider for .NET 4, Managed Driver 12.2.0.1.0 Oracle Providers for
> - ASP.NET 4 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: Which provider did you install? The managed driver or the unmanaged? Which version did you install?

Comment: See edit in question, new one is the managed i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of installing of the Oracle tools before getting it to work. Not an expert, but I found many installations of my "Oracle Home". In order to uninstall versions that I did not want, I used the Oracle Universal Installer. This is found (for Windows 7) in "Start Menu -> All Programs -> Oracle-Ora Client-your specific client -> Oracle Installation Products.

Run the installer and choose which oracle home you want to uninstall. You should be able to determine which one is the one that you want to uninstall by looking at Registry Keys, HKLM->Software->Oracle. Also HKLM->SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node->ORACLE. There may be others, search for Oracle keys.

SO figure out which oracle home you want to uninstall and use the Universal Installer to remove it. This should preserve the installation that you want and remove the one you don't. I'm not an expert, just offering what has worked for me.

In Visual Studio 2017, when I create new connection (using the wizard), there is a hard-coded path to a TNSNAMES.ORA file, that can't be changed through the wizard. It is set up through the above-mentioned registry keys. This is key to mapping your Data Source to an actual database. Hope this is helpful.